# MySql innodb_buffer_pool_size for improving performance

Tags: mysql

Can we set MySql innodb_buffer_pool_size dynamically ?
We can do the same at startup my modifying the my.cnf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no, it is only a server startup parameter (according to [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html)).

You can find all dynamic system variables [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynamic-system-variables.html) (for version 5.1):

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/dynamic-system-variables.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently not. But it will be possible in 5.7:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-online-resize.html

Older versions need a restart to change that setting.